# creating and styling a <div> within a page

Tags: pages

I want to create and style a section of some WordPress Pages that will be a kind of inset section: that is, it will be like an "aside" to the main text, so it will be a special font and color and so forth.

I tried adding `<div>` and `</div>` around some paragraphs in the text editor, with the class `inset`. I then added some custom CSS styling this red. It worked!

However, what I want to do now is adjust the width and indentation of this div block, and give it a gray background. What is a good way to go about doing this?

I understand that the div is probably contained within other divs that make up the wordpress page. How much do I need to understand about the structure of a Wordpress Page in general to accomplish this and not run into strange interactions with existing structural elements?

Alternatively is there a plugin or widget that would make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a styled section/div in your page/post content by using [WP shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). 
if you could manage a time then you could create your custom shortcode with your requirement. But if not then you could select available plugins here: [Shortcode Plugins](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-shortcode-plugins-for-design/?fbc=b&utm_expid=3606929-104.UORT_bNFTQmA2CgLFPRuGg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.np%2F)